How do I get grades for algebra, geometry, and computer science?
Here we have the Main method
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var group = new List<SchoolBoy>();
    group.Add(new SchoolBoy
    {
        Class = 8,
        Surname = "Smith",
        Initials = "TK",
        Mark = 5,
        Object = "Algebra"
    });
    group.Add(new SchoolBoy
    {
        Class = 8,
        Surname = "Smith",
        Initials = "TK",
        Mark = 4,
        Object = "Informatics"
    });
    group.Add(new SchoolBoy
    {
        Class = 8,
        Surname = "Smith",
        Initials = "TK",
        Mark = 3,
        Object = "Geometry"
    });

    var result = group.GroupBy(g => new { g.Class, g.Surname, g.Initials})
        .Select(s => new
        {
            s.Key.Class,
            s.Key.Surname,
            s.Key.Initials,
            Algebra = ???,
            Geometry = ???,
            Informatics = ???
        }).OrderBy(o => o.Class);

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class: {item.Class} | Surname: {item.Surname} | Initials: {item.Initials} | Algebra:{item.Algebra}" +
            $"| Geometry: {item.Geometry} | Informatics: {item.Informatics}");
    }
}

Algebra = s.Count(s => s.Object == "Algebra"),
But here it is clear that 1 will output.
I want to get algebra 5 geometry 3 computer science 4 this is for an 8th grade student

You might want to consider your data model, like separating the course and grade from the person.  Also, since this seem like homework, it might be useful to include the actual problem description in addition to your attempt at solving it.

You don't want to count the number of Algebra records, but the Sum or possibly Average of the Mark properties

Even if we have at most one item with given Object per student we should query for it. Let's do it with a help of SingleOrDefault, to be sure that we don't have two or more conflicting records:
var result = group
  .GroupBy(item => (item.Class, item.Surname, item.Initials),
           item => (item.Object, item.Mark))
  .Select(student => (
     Class       : student.Key.Class, 
     Surname     : student.Key.Surname,
     Initials    : student.Key.Initials,

     Algebra     : student
       .SingleOrDefault(item => item.Object == "Algebra")
      ?.Mark ?? -1,

     Geometry    : student
       .SingleOrDefault(item => item.Object == "Geometry")
      ?.Mark ?? -1,

     Informatics : student
       .SingleOrDefault(item => item.Object == "Informatics")
      ?.Mark ?? -1
   ))


There should be only one assessment per subject

@TICH: in this case we can drop aggregation, but put SingleOrDefault instead.
